# map a rbms to a dfs

Tags: hadoop, cloud, cassandra, hbase, xwiki

I'm trying to take xwiki (rbms) and map it to a cloud base (dfs) without using MySQL. Any ideas?

Comment: What is your intention to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Officially, only RDBMSs known to Hibernate are supported, so there's no support for nosql databases yet. There is a [GSoC project proposed](http://dev.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/GoogleSummerOfCode/XWikionAppEngineprototype) for developing support for AppEngine, and one of the research projects that XWiki is participating in, [Compatible One](http://compatibleone.org/bin/Main/), also needs cloud storage for XWiki. So, official support for clouds is going to come pretty soon.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look up sqoop -- a tool to move data from a relational database to hbase and back again